# Creating a 32x8 mux on a PCB for a custom PS/2 device

Tags: ps2

I’m designing a PS/2 device that takes 32 switch inputs and send them via a parallel in/serial out IC (SN74HC165) which sends the data signal and the parity bits etc. Putting this onto a PCB seems plausible but I’m not sure how to take 32 separate pins and load the parallel inputs of the IC with different byte data for each input.

Comment: Either you put four chips and load 32 bits with one signal, or you have to build a matrix. If you have an MCU the MCU could scan a matrix directly and you don't need shift registers at all. But we don't know how you intend to do it and whether it is a good way. Please fill in the details.

Comment: If you do figure out how to get your 32 inputs sent thru the HC165 8 bits at a time - how will you tell them apart at the other end? How will you know that *this* set of 8 bits came form the 3rd set or 8 switches, what *that* set came from the 1st set of switches? I think your plans need a bit more thought put into them...

Comment: the SN74HC165 does not generate a parity bit

Comment: Plan is to load the bits onto the IC in parallel and have another of the same IC generate the parity bits to send in serial after the first IC.

Comment: Suppose I want to send 32 different keystrokes on a ps/2 keyboard, that is essentially what the idea is with this.